# WinRTXAML Toolkit BindableSelection not working properly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a problem binding to the SelectedItems property of a ListView. 
I have a property in the ViewModel that looks like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _FilteredCountries;
    public ObservableCollection<string> FilteredCountries
    {
        get { return _FilteredCountries; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _FilteredCountries)
            {
                _FilteredCountries = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FilteredCountries");
            }
        }
    }
```

and in XAML i have created a ListView like this in a Popup:

```
<Popup>
   <ListView 
      ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList}"
      SelectionMode="Multiple"
      extensions:ListViewExtensions.BindableSelection="{Binding FilteredCountries, Mode=TwoWay}">
</Popup>
```

When i open the popup for the first time and select some items, the FilteredCountries collection changes and contains the selected items. But after I close the popup and open it again to select or deselect more items the FilteredCountries collection does not change, It stays the same as after the first time.
This looks for me like the binding mode is set to OneTime, but it isn't.

Comment: Could you create a small isolated repro project?

Comment: Ok I have done that. Should I upload the project folder somewhere?

Comment: You can use DropBox, Skype or something like that.

Comment: ok [here](http://db.tt/aT2P0Vxo) it is. I don't know. maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's interesting, it seems to be affected by a bug in how most of my attached behaviors are implemented. Basically to avoid leaking views bound to persistent view models - I detach the behavior handler when the control gets unloaded, but it never gets reattached when the same instance of your control gets loaded again (when your popup reopens). I will need to revise how I implement my attached behaviors. Also the behavior assumes the selection is empty when first marrying the list to the view model, so it needs an update to work in your scenario.

A fix for you for now would be to always use a new instance of your ListView, but also use an updated version of the behavior. To use a new ListView instance every time you can do this:

```
<Popup x:Name="CountryListPopup" IsOpen="False" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Grid x:Name="CountryListPopupGrid" Background="#323232" Opacity="0.8">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate
                x:Name="ListViewTemplate">
                <ListView
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList}"
                    Background="WhiteSmoke"
                    BorderThickness="4"
                    BorderBrush="#323232"
                    SelectionMode="Multiple"
                    extensions:ListViewExtensions.BindableSelection="{Binding FilteredCountries, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Margin="20">
                                <TextBlock
                                    Text="{Binding}"
                                    Margin="30,0,0,0"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    FontSize="18" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="CountryOKButton" Content="OK" FontSize="26" Click="CountryOKButton_OnClick" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>

    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

And in your code behind:

```
private ListView _listViewInstance;
private void CountryListButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CountryListPopupGrid.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    CountryListPopupGrid.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
    _listViewInstance = (ListView)ListViewTemplate.LoadContent();
    CountryListPopupGrid.Children.Add(_listViewInstance);
    CountryListPopup.IsOpen = true;
}

private void CountryOKButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainPageViewModel vm = this.DataContext as MainPageViewModel;
    foreach (string filteredCountry in vm.FilteredCountries)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(filteredCountry);
    }
    CountryListPopup.IsOpen = false;
    CountryListPopupGrid.Children.Remove(_listViewInstance);
    _listViewInstance = null;
}
```

Updated version of the behavior:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension methods and attached properties for the ListView class.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ListViewExtensions
    {
        #region BindableSelection
        /// <summary>
        /// BindableSelection Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSelectionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "BindableSelection",
                typeof (object),
                typeof (ListViewExtensions),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnBindableSelectionChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the BindableSelection property. This dependency property 
        /// indicates the list of selected items that is synchronized
        /// with the items selected in the ListView.
        /// </summary>
        public static ObservableCollection<object> GetBindableSelection(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<object>)d.GetValue(BindableSelectionProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the BindableSelection property. This dependency property 
        /// indicates the list of selected items that is synchronized
        /// with the items selected in the ListView.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetBindableSelection(
            DependencyObject d,
            ObservableCollection<object> value)
        {
            d.SetValue(BindableSelectionProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the BindableSelection property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">
        /// The <see cref="DependencyObject"/> on which
        /// the property has changed value.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="e">
        /// Event data that is issued by any event that
        /// tracks changes to the effective value of this property.
        /// </param>
        private static void OnBindableSelectionChanged(
            DependencyObject d,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            dynamic oldBindableSelection = e.OldValue;
            dynamic newBindableSelection = d.GetValue(BindableSelectionProperty);

            if (oldBindableSelection != null)
            {
                var handler = GetBindableSelectionHandler(d);
                SetBindableSelectionHandler(d, null);
                handler.Detach();
            }

            if (newBindableSelection != null)
            {
                var handler = new ListViewBindableSelectionHandler(
                    (ListViewBase)d, newBindableSelection);
                SetBindableSelectionHandler(d, handler);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region BindableSelectionHandler
        /// <summary>
        /// BindableSelectionHandler Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSelectionHandlerProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "BindableSelectionHandler",
                typeof (ListViewBindableSelectionHandler),
                typeof (ListViewExtensions),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the BindableSelectionHandler property. This dependency property 
        /// indicates BindableSelectionHandler for a ListView - used
        /// to manage synchronization of BindableSelection and SelectedItems.
        /// </summary>
        public static ListViewBindableSelectionHandler GetBindableSelectionHandler(
            DependencyObject d)
        {
            return
                (ListViewBindableSelectionHandler)
                d.GetValue(BindableSelectionHandlerProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the BindableSelectionHandler property. This dependency property 
        /// indicates BindableSelectionHandler for a ListView - used to manage synchronization of BindableSelection and SelectedItems.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetBindableSelectionHandler(
            DependencyObject d,
            ListViewBindableSelectionHandler value)
        {
            d.SetValue(BindableSelectionHandlerProperty, value);
        }
        #endregion

        #region ItemToBringIntoView
        /// <summary>
        /// ItemToBringIntoView Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemToBringIntoViewProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "ItemToBringIntoView",
                typeof (object),
                typeof (ListViewExtensions),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnItemToBringIntoViewChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the ItemToBringIntoView property. This dependency property 
        /// indicates the item that should be brought into view.
        /// </summary>
        public static object GetItemToBringIntoView(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (object)d.GetValue(ItemToBringIntoViewProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the ItemToBringIntoView property. This dependency property 
        /// indicates the item that should be brought into view when first set.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetItemToBringIntoView(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            d.SetValue(ItemToBringIntoViewProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the ItemToBringIntoView property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">
        /// The <see cref="DependencyObject"/> on which
        /// the property has changed value.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="e">
        /// Event data that is issued by any event that
        /// tracks changes to the effective value of this property.
        /// </param>
        private static void OnItemToBringIntoViewChanged(
            DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            object newItemToBringIntoView =
                (object)d.GetValue(ItemToBringIntoViewProperty);

            if (newItemToBringIntoView != null)
            {
                var listView = (ListView)d;
                listView.ScrollIntoView(newItemToBringIntoView);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Scrolls a vertical ListView to the bottom.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="listView"></param>
        public static void ScrollToBottom(this ListView listView)
        {
            var scrollViewer = listView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight);
        }
    }

    public class ListViewBindableSelectionHandler
    {
        private ListViewBase _listView;
        private dynamic _boundSelection;
        private readonly NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler _handler;

        public ListViewBindableSelectionHandler(
            ListViewBase listView, dynamic boundSelection)
        {
            _handler = OnBoundSelectionChanged;
            Attach(listView, boundSelection);
        }

        private void Attach(ListViewBase listView, dynamic boundSelection)
        {
            _listView = listView;
            _listView.Unloaded += OnListViewUnloaded;
            _listView.SelectionChanged += OnListViewSelectionChanged;
            _boundSelection = boundSelection;
            _listView.SelectedItems.Clear();

            foreach (object item in _boundSelection)
            {
                if (!_listView.SelectedItems.Contains(item))
                {
                    _listView.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }

            var eventInfo =
                _boundSelection.GetType().GetDeclaredEvent("CollectionChanged");
            eventInfo.AddEventHandler(_boundSelection, _handler);
            //_boundSelection.CollectionChanged += OnBoundSelectionChanged;
        }

        private void OnListViewSelectionChanged(
            object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (dynamic item in e.RemovedItems)
            {
                if (_boundSelection.Contains(item))
                {
                    _boundSelection.Remove(item);
                }
            }
            foreach (dynamic item in e.AddedItems)
            {
                if (!_boundSelection.Contains(item))
                {
                    _boundSelection.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnBoundSelectionChanged(
            object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action ==
                NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            {
                _listView.SelectedItems.Clear();

                foreach (var item in _boundSelection)
                {
                    if (!_listView.SelectedItems.Contains(item))
                    {
                        _listView.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }

                return;
            }

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    if (_listView.SelectedItems.Contains(item))
                    {
                        _listView.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    if (!_listView.SelectedItems.Contains(item))
                    {
                        _listView.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnListViewUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Detach();
        }

        internal void Detach()
        {
            _listView.Unloaded -= OnListViewUnloaded;
            _listView.SelectionChanged -= OnListViewSelectionChanged;
            _listView = null;
            var eventInfo =
                _boundSelection.GetType().GetDeclaredEvent("CollectionChanged");
            eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(_boundSelection, _handler);
            _boundSelection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use a new ListView each time - you would need to comment out this line in the behavior: `_listView.Unloaded += OnListViewUnloaded;`